# Accessing custom UITableViewCell from ViewController using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have created a Custom UITableViewCell in ViewController

[image]

[image]

I can access my ViewController

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                        @"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myId"];
```

But how can i access HomeScreenTableViewCell ?

Thanks.

Comment: create a tableview in viewcontroller first then add tableviewcell in tableview.

Comment: why not create seperate .xib file for custom tableviewcell?

Comment: and if you don't have tableview, why you need UITableViewCell?

Comment: follow this tutorial:http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: @johnykumar this is what i was following but i am unable to drag a UITableViewCell in the drawing area of storyboard.

Comment: @Usama i am adding tableview programatically in UIViewController.

Comment: @Usama i tried created a separate xib file but somehow it was not adjusting with width and height of the ViewController

Comment: if you are creating tableview programatically then assign delegate to self and in delegate methods create cell with reuseIdentifier which you have to assign to cell.

Comment: create .h and .m file for cell and assign to cell from identity inspector on right.

Comment: I have already assigned delegates and while implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath i want to load the HomeScreenTableViewCell from the storyboard.

Comment: have you assigned that HomeScreenTableViewCell class  to cell ?

Comment: @Amit you can follow this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: @Usama its in swift he is working in objective C.but screens willbe helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not access like that, you can either create Custom `UITableViewCell` with a seperate .xib or can create prototype cell with `UITableView` placed in storyboard